# Passing variables from GUI to current workspace, MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I designed an app using app designer, which runs an .m file when pushbutton is pressed.  But before that execution, I am browsing some xlsx files and storing there data in some variables, and I am using `assignin` function to export those variables. These variables are in turn used in the script(.m file), But what I have observed is these variables are present in base workspace which is different from current workspace. Is there any way, that I can pass them to the current workspace.

`assignin("base",'name',name2)`

This is just a trail GUI

```
classdef app < matlab.apps.AppBase

    % Properties that correspond to app components
    properties (Access = public)
        UIFigure        matlab.ui.Figure
        ContinueButton  matlab.ui.control.Button
        Button          matlab.ui.control.Button
        Button2         matlab.ui.control.Button
        Button3         matlab.ui.control.Button
    end

    
  
    

    % Callbacks that handle component events
    methods (Access = private)

        % Code that executes after component creation
        function startupFcn(app)
            %app.ds
            %uiwait(app.UIFigure);
        end

        % Button pushed function: ContinueButton
        function ContinueButtonPushed(app, event)
            name = 'string';
            assignin("base",'name',name)
            run("trail.m")
            closereq
            %set(handle.Operation)
        end

        % Close request function: UIFigure
        function UIFigureCloseRequest(app, event)
            delete(app)
            %uiresume(app.UIFigure);
        end
    end

    % Component initialization
    methods (Access = private)

        % Create UIFigure and components
        function createComponents(app)

            % Create UIFigure and hide until all components are created
            app.UIFigure = uifigure('Visible', 'off');
            app.UIFigure.Position = [100 100 640 480];
            app.UIFigure.Name = 'MATLAB App';
            app.UIFigure.CloseRequestFcn = createCallbackFcn(app, @UIFigureCloseRequest, true);
            app.UIFigure.Pointer = 'hand';

            % Create ContinueButton
            app.ContinueButton = uibutton(app.UIFigure, 'push');
            app.ContinueButton.ButtonPushedFcn = createCallbackFcn(app, @ContinueButtonPushed, true);
            app.ContinueButton.Position = [164 106 262 92];
            app.ContinueButton.Text = 'Continue';

            % Create Button
            app.Button = uibutton(app.UIFigure, 'push');
            app.Button.Position = [454 254 100 22];

            % Create Button2
            app.Button2 = uibutton(app.UIFigure, 'push');
            app.Button2.Position = [104 254 100 22];
            app.Button2.Text = 'Button2';

            % Create Button3
            app.Button3 = uibutton(app.UIFigure, 'push');
            app.Button3.Position = [301 335 100 22];
            app.Button3.Text = 'Button3';

            % Show the figure after all components are created
            app.UIFigure.Visible = 'on';
        end
    end

    % App creation and deletion
    methods (Access = public)

        % Construct app
        function app = app

            % Create UIFigure and components
            createComponents(app)

            % Register the app with App Designer
            registerApp(app, app.UIFigure)

            % Execute the startup function
            runStartupFcn(app, @startupFcn)

            if nargout == 0
                clear app
            end
        end

        % Code that executes before app deletion
        function delete(app)

            % Delete UIFigure when app is deleted
            delete(app.UIFigure)
        end
    end
 end
```

This is the trail.m script file

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% trail.m %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

clc;clear

suma = 90;
sumb = 100;
total = suma+sumb;

disp(name);
```

Comment: What do you mean with “pass to the current workspace”? Do you want to fetch these variables from the base workspace? You might want to instead put them into the GUI’s context. Not knowing the structure of your program makes it hard to suggest something specific.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Sorry for the ambiguity.  Passing into the current workspace mean, that when a variable is generated in a GUI, I want to push them into my current workspace. Is that clear. If not I can attach some code.

Comment: But what is your current workspace when a GUI callback is running? It’s the callback’s workspace! Whatever function was running when the user pressed a button in the GUI is paused, and therefore no longer current. I think adding some minimal code that demonstrates your general architecture would be useful.

Comment: @CrisLuengo updated the question

Comment: @CrisLuengo Not to get too technical here, but: when a callback is running, the current workspace is the callback's workspace, but it's also important that the "caller" workspace is not guaranteed to be the GUI-builder's workspace, or anything in particular! The GUI call stack is divorced from the main M-code execution call stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use handles, not variables or `assignin`.

Instead of trying to assign variables directly in a workspace (which is an advanced, brittle technique), I suggest that you use a pass-by-reference `handle` style object to pass values back and forth between your main function and your GUI callbacks. A `containers.Map` object will do the trick (since it is a handle), or you can define a custom class using `classdef MySharedData < handle`. Create the object in your call function and store it in a variable there. Then stick the object in an appdata on one of your figure handles that is visible to your GUI callback functions. To pass data back to the calling/main function, have your GUI callback assign or update values/properties on your shared handle object.

Or you could just stick the values directly in appdata on your GUI handles. They act as handles, too, and this is the traditional Matlab way of passing data back and forth between a calling function and GUI callbacks.

Comment: Thank you for the response, But frankly not aware of the handles, I get the concept little bit, but i am afraid that I cannot code it. I updated my question by adding code to it, Please lemme know the additions I need to make.

Comment: In Matlab, a `handle` object is just a thing that has pass-by-reference behavior, instead of pass-by-value copy-on-write behavior like normal Matlab values. I'm afraid this is something you're going to have to understand if you want to understand basic Matlab programming.

I'm heading to bed for the night; I'll review your edits tomorrow. Thanks for updating your question in response to feedback!

Answer (score 1):

This function:

```
   function ContinueButtonPushed(app, event)
        name = 'string';
        assignin("base",'name',name)
        run("trail.m")
        closereq
        %set(handle.Operation)
    end
```

can be simplified to:

```
   function ContinueButtonPushed(app, event)
        name = 'string';
        trail
        closereq
        %set(handle.Operation)
    end
```

Because the `trail` command will launch the `trail.m` script, and scripts share the caller’s workspace. So it will see the local `name` variable.

In your script `trail`, make sure you don’t clear all variables: remove the `clc;clear` line. Otherwise you’re clearing the `name` variable you are trying to use!

Comment: Thanks its working now. But I Can't any of my variables in the workspace, because all are in caller's workspace.   If we try like @Andrewjanke said in his answer, probably we can get in the current workspace.  Can I know how to do it. Thanks